# AUTHENTICATIONFAILED - LOGIN Invalid credentials

Tags: python, email, imap, yahoo, thunderbird

I´m trying to connect my python-scrip with Thunderbird. Thunderbird uses my yahoo-mail.

With following code I should be able to connect to Thunderbird:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(config.server)
M.login(config.user, config.passwd)
M.select("inbox")
```

but I have the following issue:

```
Loaded classifier and label encoder with tag 'productive'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 51, in <module>
M.login(config.user, config.passwd)
File 
"C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\ anaconda3\envs\nn_dev\lib\imaplib.py", line 
593, in login
raise self.error(dat[-1])
imaplib.error: b'[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] LOGIN Invalid credentials'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Thunderbird is a client, not a server.  What is your server?  What is your username?  Did you include the @yahoo.com (or whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect to Yahoo with Thunderbird, you should be able to connect directly to Yahoo with Python: just use the same login data you used in Thunderbird.

Otherwise, maybe there is some type of block on the Yahoo side (for example, if you activated [two-step authentication](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-third-party-passwords-sln15241.html))

Comment: There was a block on the yahoo side. I allowed apps with lower security features in IT security settings of yahoo (https://help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-third-party-passwords-sln15241.html). Now it works. Thank you very much!